# Sending notification from nodejs server to angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, eventemitter

I have an angularjs module deployed on a nodejs server. The nodejs also has an REST end point.

Whenever I get a hit in the nodejs REST end point, I want to update a scope variable in angularjs script and then I have to redirect the user to a page after that.

I thought of using event emitter, but i couldn't do that since the event emitter require response.write, and I couldn't redirect to the page after this.

Is there any way I can do achieve this ?

Comment: you want to update scope variable when calling Rest end point?

Answer (score 1):

You should use EventSource to send notifications to client. It's built for that purpose. You can use [EventSource package](https://github.com/EventSource/eventsource) for that purpose in Node.js.

You shouldn't redirect the client from the server, if you're using Angular's routing. Instead let the Angular Router redirect after it receives the push notification.